# Razor declarative helper passing model as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

How can I pass the model to a custom html helper as a parameter?

Currently I have the following file

```
@helper LabelFor(string label, string hint)
{
    <label for="@label">@label</label>
    <span class="mif-info"
          data-role="hint"
          data-hint-background="bg-blue"
          data-hint-color="fg-white"
          data-hint-mode="1"
          data-hint-position="top"
          data-hint="@hint"></span>
}
```

Which is called with

```
@MyHelpers.LabelFor(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title).ToString(), "Description")
```

How can I simplify it to

```
@MyHelpers.LabelFor(model => model.Title, "Description")
```

Comment: Its not possible to use an expression (at least with generic type arguments) in `@helper`. Use a `HtmlHelper` extension method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can achieve the same using MVC DisplayTemplates. Did you try that path?

Comment: I could, but I'm seeing if there's a way to do it with a custom razor helper.